# Crud con expressjs y mongodb

Tags: nodejs, mvc, mongodb, express, mongoose

Estoy creando un crud de usuarios con express y mongodb he creado mis controladores, servicios y rutas, para obtener los usuarios si funciona pero para crear un nuevo usuario no me funciona.
User es el modelo que estoy llamando

```
//Este es el controlador
const createUser = async (data) => {
    const newUser = await new User.insertOne({
        firstName: data.firstName,
        lastName: data.lastName,
        email: data.email,
        password: data.password,
        country: data.country,
    });
    return newUser;
};
```

```
//Este es el servicio
const createUser = (req, res) => {
    const { firstName, lastName, email, password, country } = req.body;
    if (firstName && lastName && email && password && country) {
        controllers
            .createUser({ firstName, lastName, email, password, country })
            .then((response) => res.status(201).json(response))
            .catch((e) => res.status(400).json({ msg: e.msg }));
    } else {
        res.status(400).json({
            msg: "all field must be completed",
            field: {
                firstName: "string",
                lastName: "string",
                email: "string",
                password: "string",
                country: "string",
            },
        });
    }
};
```

```
router.get("/", services.getAllUsers);

router.post("/", services.createUser);
```

Comment: El problema es aquí: `await new User.insertOne({ ... });`. Estás mezclando el constructor del modelo (`new`) con el método `insertOne`. En tu caso debería ser solo: `await new User({ ... });`, luego debes usar `await newUser.save()`. Prueba eso y comenta el resultado. También puedes leer la [documentación](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html). Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Tal como digo en mi comentario, el método (lo que llamas controlador) para crear un usario tiene un problema:

```js
const createUser = async (data) => {
  const newUser = await new User.insertOne({  // <- AQUÍ!
    firstName: data.firstName,
    lastName: data.lastName,
    email: data.email,
    password: data.password,
    country: data.country,
  });
  return newUser;
};
```

El problema es que estás encadenando el método `insertOne` al constructor del Modelo (`new`). Lo cual es incorrecto.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Tal como se desprende de la documentación, para insertar un nuevo documento en tu colección tienes 3 formas de hacerlo a partir de un modelo de Mongoose.

**Usando el constructor `new`**

Si vas a usar el constructor `new`, debe saber que el resultado obtenido no es almacenado directamentamente en la base de datos, simplemente estás creando una instancia del objeto `Dcoument` de Mongoose.

Con esta instancia puedes modificar, validar y otras cosas antes de almacenar el documento en la base de datos. Sin embargo, puedes simplemente almacenarlo usando el método `save()` que es parte de toda instancia de un Documento. Por ejemplo:

```js
const createUser = async (data) => {
  const newUser = await new User({
    firstName: data.firstName,
    lastName: data.lastName,
    email: data.email,
    password: data.password,
    country: data.country,
  });
  await newUser.save();
  return newUser;
};
```

Ahora bien, podría darse el caso de error al guardar un documento en la base de datos, es por ello que cada vez que uses `async / await`, siempre es buena idea usar `try ... catch` para capaturar cualquier excepción durante el proceso.

Por ejemplo:

```js
const createUser = async (data) => {
  try {
    const newUser = await new User({
      firstName: data.firstName,
      lastName: data.lastName,
      email: data.email,
      password: data.password,
      country: data.country,
    });
    await newUser.save();
    return newUser;
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.error(e.message);
    return null;
  }
};
```

Así, si ocurre un error podremos manejarlo, mostrar el mensaje y devolver `null` que podría indicar que el usuario no fue creado.

**Usando `insertOne`**

Si deseas usar `insertOne`, debes tomar en cuenta tres cosas:

1. El método [`insertOne`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertOne/) es un método del objeto Collection de MongoDB y no del Modelo, o del Documento de Mongoose (son cosas diferentes). Es por ello que `new Model().insertOne()` no es correcto.
2. El método `insertOne` no realiza las validaciones sobre el documento a insertar, ya que no forma parte del Modelo, sino de la colección, y como las colecciones en MongoDB son *schemaless*, no hay validaciones sobre las mismas, excepto las de tipo índice.
3. El método que realmente debes usar es [`insertMany`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model-insertMany), que recibe una lista de documentos para insertar a la base de datos, validando cada uno de acuerdo a las validaciones del Modelo.

Por ejemplo:

```js
const createUser = async (data) => {
  try {
    const newUser = await User.insertMany([
      {
        firstName: data.firstName,
        lastName: data.lastName,
        email: data.email,
        password: data.password,
        country: data.country,
      }
    ]);
    if(!newUser.length) {
      throw new Error('Documento no pudo ser crewado);
    }
    return newUser[0];  // <- Como hemos creado 1 sólo documento, se usa [0]
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.error(e.message);
    return null;
  }
};
```

**Usando `create`**

Otra forma de insertar un documento en la base de datos es usando el método [`create`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-create) del Modelo. Por ejemplo:

```js
const createUser = async (data) => {
  try {
    const newUser = await User.create({
      firstName: data.firstName,
      lastName: data.lastName,
      email: data.email,
      password: data.password,
      country: data.country,
    });
    return newUser;
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.error(e.message);
    return null;
  }
};
```

Al igual que `insertOne`, el método `create` realiza la operación en la base de datos, y devuelve una Promesa.

Puedes leer la diferencia entre [Modelo y Documento](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html#documents-vs-models)

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver tu problema.

Comment: Gracias me sirvió tus soluciones, pasa que yo modularizo los procesos, así que las promesas las resuelvo en un modulo aparte con then catch
Postd: Los métodos que mencionaste acá   como .save o .create son de mongosee? porque revise la documentación de mongoDB y no parecen allí

Comment: Si, efectivamente `save()` y `create()` son métodos de Mongoose.